# Time complexity of search operation on hash tables using separate chaining

Tags: time-complexity, hashtable, load-factor

It's usually said that on average the cost of the search operation on a hash table is O(1) because the length of a given list on the table is proportional to the load factor. What I don't get is that the load factor clearly depends on the number of entries we want to store so it is not necessarily a constant. Suppose we are frequently adding new entries, doesn't that make the length of an average list depend on the number of entries too? How is the operation O(1)?

Sorry for my english. It's not my main language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many implementations resize the table so that the load factor stays bounded by a constant. Resize takes time proportional to number of items stored, but if done infrequently enough it balances out so that insertions take **amortized** constant time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So without resizing the operation is not O(1) on average? Just to see if I got it.

Comment: Yes, without resize the load factor will not have a constant bound